# Can I use OnTime Method to schedule a macro to run at a specific time each week?

Tags: vba, automation

I have some work tasks that need to be done weekly for which i have can do a macro. But now I'm wondering if I can take it one step further and schedule when it should run.

I tried

```
Sub schemalägg()
Application.OnTime TimeValue("19:16:30"), "Hej", , True



End Sub
```

It does trigger the macro at a specific time. But i want to add that it should only do so at a certain weekday.

I then tried using Windows Scheduler (then I wouldn´t need ontime method at all) but didn´t manage to get to file to open.

[image: Picture link 1]

Instead this happend
[Picture link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWn9x.png)

Comment: in the code that is called, just put a line that exits the sub if the day is not the one you want.  ie: `IF Format(Date(), "dddd") <> "Thursday" then Exit Sub` or something like that.